# System.now() gives a different hour value and System.now().hour() gives a different value. can any one tell me why so?

Tags: system

```
String day = string.valueOf(system.now().day());
String month = string.valueOf(system.now().month());
String hour = string.valueOf(system.now().hour());
String minute = string.valueOf(system.now().minute());
String second = string.valueOf(system.now().second());
String year = string.valueOf(system.now().year());

String strTime = year+'-'+month+'-'+day+' '+hour+':'+minute+':'+second ;

system.debug(strTime);
system.debug(system.now());
```

> output 1: 2015-7-7 14:5:55
>
> output 2: 2015-07-07 08:35:55

================================================

Comment: Try looking at `Json.serialize()` to see underlying value irrespective of timezone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DateTime objects have built-in support for the user's timezone. So [DateTime.hour](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_hour):

> Returns the hour component of a Datetime in the local time zone of the context user.

[DateTime.format](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format) also includes the timezone offset but just doing a default DateTime conversion to a string looks like it presents the underlying GMT value.

Answer (score 1):

System.now() returns the DateTime in GMT time zone, whereas System.now().hour() is the method of DateTime class, which returns the local time zone of the context user.